# Wagtail - more class arguments than parameters? Whats going on?

Tags: python, django, arguments, metaclass, wagtail

Hi Stackoverflow Community

I have been trying to understand how Django (and Wagtail's Stream-field) work under the hood. Doing that I learned about metaclasses and believe to have a handle on the principle. There is however one piece of code that confuses me (see below).

When we follow the StreamField definitions this code seems to pass a list of tuples to a class constructor that doesn't appear to accommodate for a list of this kind. How can this work?

Any advice would be highly appreciated. Here the code:

**models.py**

This is where we define the StreamField. It takes a list of tuples of format ('title', blockType). Our objective is to follow the StreamField call:

```
class BlogPage(Page):
    blogElement = StreamField([
        ('heading', blocks.CharBlock(classname="full title")),
        ('paragraph', blocks.TextBlock()),
        ('picture', ImageChooserBlock()),
    ], default=[])
```

**fields.py>StreamField**

When we follow the call to StreamField we arrive at the following class constructor. Here the call to ***StreamBlock(block_types)*** is **where it gets confusing:**

```
class StreamField(models.Field):
    def __init__(self, block_types, **kwargs):
        if isinstance(block_types, Block):
            self.stream_block = block_types
        elif isinstance(block_types, type):
            self.stream_block = block_types()
        else:
            self.stream_block = StreamBlock(block_types)
        super(StreamField, self).__init__(**kwargs)
```

**StreamBlock**

While the call to the class constructor takes **block_types** as an argument (contains a list of three tuples defined in models.py) the receiving class constructor takes a call to six.with_metaclass as an argument (code included below):

```
class StreamBlock(six.with_metaclass(DeclarativeSubBlocksMetaclass, BaseStreamBlock)):
    pass
```

**MY QUESTION**

How is this possible? six.with_metaclass itself is a call to a method which takes two arguments <> and <>, both class constructors in their own right (code included below).

Shouldn't StreamBlock accommodate to receive arguments that fit the **block_types** which in turn contain the list of three tuples defined in **models.py**? I am sure i may be missing something here but just can't see it. Any advice would be highly appreciated.

Z

**For Context**
I included the code for the other code-pieces for context below. I figured out how the six.with_metaclass works in this post: [Wow does six.with_metaclass() work?
][1] but I am struggling with the question above.

**six.with_metaclass**

```
def with_metaclass(meta, *bases):
    """Create a base class with a metaclass."""
    # This requires a bit of explanation: the basic idea is to make a dummy
    # metaclass for one level of class instantiation that replaces itself with
    # the actual metaclass.
    class metaclass(meta):

        def __new__(cls, name, this_bases, d):
            print("In with_metaclass: %s " %d )
            return meta(name, bases, d)
    return type.__new__(metaclass, 'temporary_class', (), {})
```

**DeclarativeSubBlocksMetaclass**

```
class DeclarativeSubBlocksMetaclass(BaseBlock):
"""
Metaclass that collects sub-blocks declared on the base classes.
(cheerfully stolen from      https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/forms/forms.py)
"""
def __new__(mcs, name, bases, attrs):
    # Collect sub-blocks declared on the current class.
    # These are available on the class as `declared_blocks`
    current_blocks = []
    for key, value in list(attrs.items()):
        if isinstance(value, Block):
            current_blocks.append((key, value))
            value.set_name(key)
            attrs.pop(key)
    current_blocks.sort(key=lambda x: x[1].creation_counter)
    attrs['declared_blocks'] = collections.OrderedDict(current_blocks)

    new_class = (super(DeclarativeSubBlocksMetaclass, mcs).__new__(mcs, name, bases, attrs))

    # Walk through the MRO, collecting all inherited sub-blocks, to make
    # the combined `base_blocks`.
    base_blocks = collections.OrderedDict()
    for base in reversed(new_class.__mro__):
        # Collect sub-blocks from base class.
        if hasattr(base, 'declared_blocks'):
            base_blocks.update(base.declared_blocks)

        # Field shadowing.
        for attr, value in base.__dict__.items():
            if value is None and attr in base_blocks:
                base_blocks.pop(attr)
    new_class.base_blocks = base_blocks

    return new_class
```

**BaseStreamBlock**

```
class BaseStreamBlock(Block):

def __init__(self, local_blocks=None, **kwargs):
    self._constructor_kwargs = kwargs

    super(BaseStreamBlock, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    # create a local (shallow) copy of base_blocks so that it can be supplemented by local_blocks
    self.child_blocks = self.base_blocks.copy()
    if local_blocks:
        for name, block in local_blocks:
            block.set_name(name)
            self.child_blocks[name] = block

    self.dependencies = self.child_blocks.values()
```

Comment: It's not the class constructor that takes `six.with_metaclass` as an argument. The class is *inheriting* from the return value of `six.with_metaclass`.

Comment: Ah! Ok. Thank you! That is very helpful. The whole metaclass entanglements must have thrown me off. So the list of tuples in block_types is essentially going to be passed on to the _init_ method inside the BaseStreamBlock class definition?

Comment: Unless you're specifically interested in Python 2/3 compatibility hacks, you're unlikely to gain any insights about StreamField from looking inside the `six` library code... as the author of the StreamField code, I've certainly never done that myself :-) I suggest you treat `six.with_metaclass` as a black box for defining a class with a given metaclass in a cross-Python-version-compatible way; then, as long as you understand metaclasses as a general Python concept (as opposed to understanding what `six` does with them), you'll be on the right track.

Comment: @gasman. How cool. So you are working for Torchbox? The interest for Streamfields comes from a little Open Source project I intend to run here in BKK. We are trying to see whether StreamFields can be expanded to support/ function like a visual composer. Hence the comprehensive inquiry. I strongly believe in Wagtail's potential for NGO deployment. Adding this feature could help many orgs adopt it in this region. Would love to be in touch. My Twitter is @ mike_nedelko.